# Error on Heroku when using Twitter API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter

I'm fairly new to programming. I made a simple Rails app where users can search for a Twitter account and then see a list of recent Tweets. Right now, everything works fine locally, but on Heroku, an error appears after I search for a Twitter username. It says: "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

What could I be doing wrong? I used the [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) for Rails in order to interface with the Twitter API.

UPDATE: The original logs did not show any errors, but when I added LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG, I found:

```
2015-11-14T20:46:12.807764+00:00 heroku[api]: Set LOG_LEVEL config vars by me@gmail.com
2015-11-14T20:46:12.807798+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by me@gmail.com
2015-11-14T20:46:12.920647+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-11-14T20:46:14.836990+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 46021 -e production`
2015-11-14T20:46:18.072236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-11-14T20:46:18.419708+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in <top (required)> at /app/config/environments/production.rb:23)
2015-11-14T20:46:19.246517+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-14 20:46:19] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-11-14T20:46:19.246524+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-14 20:46:19] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-11-14T20:46:19.246525+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-14 20:46:19] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=46021
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509393+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-14 20:46:19] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509398+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509399+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509400+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509400+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509401+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509402+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509402+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509403+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509404+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509405+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509406+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509405+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509407+00:00 app[web.1]:  bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509407+00:00 app[web.1]:  bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509411+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-14 20:46:19] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-11-14T20:46:19.509438+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-14 20:46:19] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-11-14T20:46:19.533083+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-11-14T20:46:19.533087+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-11-14T20:46:19.533087+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:24418
2015-11-14T20:46:19.533088+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-11-14T20:46:19.533089+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-11-14T20:46:19.609214+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-14T20:46:20.250573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-11-14T20:52:25.726153+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=appname.herokuapp.com request_id=839d65f2-9bb6-4c1d-908b-fad69f817a6f fwd="123.45.67.890" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=114ms status=200 bytes=1642
2015-11-14T20:52:25.952648+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-4aac4725986aee7cd976eac8d3be0ab3.js" host=appname.herokuapp.com request_id=cbced639-bba6-40d5-993a-332e54cfe320 fwd="123.45.67.890" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=90ms status=404 bytes=1829
2015-11-14T20:52:25.907640+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-018564ef5c99ab59c0936b1891ba38e6.css" host=appname.herokuapp.com request_id=bc40e739-0627-4bf4-aa51-11454137e3d9 fwd="123.45.67.890" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=68ms status=404 bytes=1829
2015-11-14T20:52:31.106562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=news&commit=Search" host=appname.herokuapp.com request_id=87845fc0-db85-47df-b918-61bc7114cb52 fwd="123.45.67.890" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=197ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

Now there are some status 404 and 500 errors. What could be causing these?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the error? this log doesn't have any error.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just updated my question with the full logs from Heroku. Unfortunately, I don't see the error there either for some reason.

Comment: You will be happy to know that it doesn't appear to be an application error. Just reboot your Heroku "box" again

Comment: Thanks. I tried `heroku restart`, but there was still an error. I then retrieved the expanded Heroku logs, and saw a few 404s and a 500. I updated my question. What do you think those are from?

Comment: From jun 2021, there is some restrictions from twitter, for running automations using twitter api on various cloud hosting platforms, including heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I needed to add my Twitter API credentials into Heroku.

```
heroku config:add TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY=<<Your twitter consumer key>>
heroku config:add TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET=<<Your twitter consumer secret>>
```

Sources:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars
- https://github.com/mortardata/twitter-gardenhose/blob/master/README.md